# Construct a map Name of one object is key, id of another is value

Tags: apex, map

I am having trouble creating this map, c2g__codaCompany__c name should be the key and ID of Journal_Staging__c should be the value.. please help? I currently have the following error:

> Loop variable must be a generic SObject or List or a concrete SObject or List of: c2g__codaCompany__c

```java
List<Journal_Staging__c> journals = new List<Journal_Staging__c>();
// map to get all companies
Map<Id, c2g__codaCompany__c> companies = New Map<Id, c2g__codaCompany__c>([Select Id, Name FROM c2g__codaCompany__c]);

// for each company, create a journal, setting that company id on the journal - pass this to list and make public 
for(c2g__codaCompany__c c : companies.keySet()) {
    journals.add(new Journal_Staging__c(
    // set company lookup - no name - auto generated - only put id not name, using get got the whole record. 
    Company__c = c.Id));
}

// insert journals to get id for jlis
insert journals;

// map of company name to journal id
List<Journal_Staging__c> getNewJournals = [Select Id, Name, Company__c FROM Journal_Staging__c];
Map<String, Id> companyJournal = New Map<String, Id>();

for(Journal_Staging__c j : [SELECT Name FROM c2g__codaCompany__c]) {
    companyJournal.put(j.Name, j.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in the line:

```
for(c2g__codaCompany__c c : companies.keySet()) {
```

Your `keySet` has type `Set<Id>`, but your `for` loop is expecting a `c2g__codaCompany__c`. Change the line to

```
for(c2g__codaCompany__c c : companies.values()) {
```

to iterate over the set of `c2g__codaCompany__c` contained in the map.

Please see the [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) class documentation for more details.